# Is it possible to animate and change the width of a div only from a specified height and leave the rest as it is?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to animate a div so that the top half(height:50px) has a width of 100px and the bottom half(height:200px) has a width of 200px. Is this possible?

See jsfiddle for example of end result that I would like to have animated in one div.

http://jsfiddle.net/vr9eX/1/

Some CSS from the JsFiddle for my example pic because StackOverflow is giving me trouble with only having a jsFiddle link:

```
#a{
    background-color:blue;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
}
#b{
   background-color:blue;
   height:200px;
   width:200px;  
}
```

Is this possible?
If yes, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Are you asking how to animate only `<div>`s that have a height of 50px or less?

Comment: A very bad english example.

Comment: don't even understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: sorry, It's hard to articulate what I would like to do.
I included a jsFiddle to show the end result and tried to edit my question as best as I could. ( I want the result of the jsfiddle but as one div)  I want to animate the bottom half of it to a width of 200px while the top half stays at 100px.

Comment: You'll allways need multiple elements to achieve your desired result. Though maybe canvas or svg would be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure hope this link help you.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/

and also this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div {
  background-color:#bca;
  width:200px;
  height:1.1em;
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid green;
  margin:3px;
  font-size:14px;
}
button {
  font-size:14px;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="go1">&raquo; Animate Block1</button>
<button id="go2">&raquo; Animate Block2</button>
<button id="go3">&raquo; Animate Both</button>

<button id="go4">&raquo; Reset</button>
<div id="block1">Block1</div>
<div id="block2">Block2</div>
<script>

$( "#go1" ).click(function(){
  $( "#block1" ).animate( { width: "90%" }, { queue: false, duration: 3000 })
     .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500 )
     .animate({ borderRightWidth: "15px" }, 1500 );
});

$( "#go2" ).click(function(){
  $( "#block2" ).animate({ width: "90%" }, 1000 )
     .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1000 )
     .animate({ borderLeftWidth: "15px" }, 1000 );
});

$( "#go3" ).click(function(){
  $( "#go1" ).add( "#go2" ).click();
});

$( "#go4" ).click(function(){
  $( "div" ).css({ width: "", fontSize: "", borderWidth: "" });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically I have one div and I want to animate the bottom half of it to a width of 200px while the top half stays at 100px.